# Creating action to get and display shopping cart object stored in session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

Hi Everyone...
              I am new in ASP.NET MVC. i have one doubt.
**without using EF** to add more products in shopping cart using **MVC** razor
**My Home controller class**

```
    public void AddOrderItem(Int64 ID, int quantity)
    {            
        OrderDO order = (OrderDO)Session["Order"];
        order.Items.Add(new OrderItem(ID, quantity));
        Session["Order"] = order;  
    }
}
 public class OrderDO
    {
        private IList<OrderItem> _items;
        public OrderDO()
        {
            this._items = new List<OrderItem>();
        }
        public IList<OrderItem> Items
        {
            get { return this._items; }
        }
    }
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public OrderItem()
        {
        }
        public OrderItem(Int64 ID, int quantity)
        {
            this.ID= ID;
            this.Quantity = quantity;
        }
        public Int64 ID{ get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

My Script in Product page is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddToCard').click(function () {
            var ProductID = $('#txtproductID').val();
            var Quantity = $('#txtQuantity').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../Home/AddOrderItem',
                data: { ID: ProductID, quantity: Quantity },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data) {

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

In the above code working properly. I am  clicking the shopping cart button , how to get the Details shopping list

```
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            OrderDO order = (OrderDO)Session["Order"];

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please add some more details? What products in what shopping card ? :)

Comment: Please also post some code and express what you tried to do to accomplish what you're willing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it as model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    OrderDO order = (OrderDO)Session["Order"];
    return PartialView(order.Items);
}
```

which will be strongly typed to this model and you could display the details:

```
@model IEnumerable<OrderItem>
@ {
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

and since you seem to be invoking this controller action with AJAX don't forget to insert the result in the DOM in your `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../Home/AddOrderItem',
    data: { ID: ProductID, quantity: Quantity },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#someContentPlaceholder').html(data);
    }
});
```